# Nvidia-304-Updates Broken on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Just tried to start my Ubuntu 14.04.2 machine with a Nivida Geforce 7600 GS. Was using Nivida-304-updates drivers. When the computer boots it completely locks up after logging in. I can get to tty1 through ctrl + alt + F1. I've purged the Nvidia drivers from there and then I can access the GUI.

Any help on getting the drivers working again?

Kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 i686
Video Card: BFG Nvidia Geforce 7600 GS OC (Needs Nivida-304-updates)

Commands used to Purge: sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* followed by sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: It seems possibly related to this bug: [link]https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1365695[/link]

Comment: Xorg Edgers drivers didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Nivida Geforce 7600 GS on a machine used infrequently.  It can boot to the login screen which looks OK, but is almost unresponsive bringing up a desktop.  Even for a guest login.  Once loaded, graphics are corrupt with icons etc showing mostly random coloured pixels. This is 304.125-0ubuntu0.0.1 and Linux kernel 3.13.0-55-generic i686 using an Intel Pentium 4.  Purging all the nvidia drivers and using the nouveau drivers works fine.

As this effects someone else other than me I have created a bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates/+bug/1467282

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug on launchpad. I actually formatted and moved over to Linux Mint 17 with XFC desktop. Way quicker and works with Nvidia drivers for the 7600